# What is the name of the widely used connectors on aluminum LED boards?

Tags: identification, connector

I've watched some smart bulb disassembling videos and noticed the following connectors (see pictures). I think such solderless connectors are very beneficial for the connections between "terminals or pads on FR4" to "aluminum LED board".

Unfortunately, I can't find the name of these connectors. I tried searching for "pluggable solderless connectors" but only found other connector types like machine pins (male and female) and several connector types from Keystone and some other types, but not the connectors from the photos. Could someone provide the name of the connectors in the pictures?

Feel free to add other similar solderless connector types for LED boards if you know any.

[image: Two different connector types on the LED boards.]

[image: Bottom of the left-side LED board from the first photo,]

Comment: Try searching for "smd connectors", I saw some that looked similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one on the left is a bottom-entry / through-board, board-to-board connector. TE makes a similar one: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/2213189-1/4486420

[image: TE 2213189-1]

{Digikey}

As does Kyocera AVX: https://www.digikey.com/short/zqmjm9jj

[image: Kyocera 009159002501906]

{Digikey}

Comment: Many thanks! Would you like to merge your two answers into one? If not, I will accept this answer as the answer that answered my question.

Comment: Since you asked about 2 different components I gave 2 answers. I will appreciate you accepting either answer, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The one on the right is not a connector but two individual board-in terminals.

They are made by Kyocera AVX, including P/N 709296001103006. There are a few parts, depending on the wire gauge.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kyocera-avx/709296001103006/4806550

[image: Kyocera 709296001103006]

{Digikey}